# Ubuntu 20.04: Cursor blinking at boot after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I've just installed NVIDIA proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-460 from additional drivers). After reboot, I get a black screen with a cursor blinking. After a few seconds, I've moved to a tty using Ctl + Alt + F2, and without giving me time to login, the graphical interface started.

I rebooted a few times, and this behavior seems to continue: it will give me a black screen with a cursor blinking until I move to a different tty, and then X starts and asks me for normal login.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: same here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

I am using nvidia-driver-460 version 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.

The GDM screen would only appear after typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

*Please comment and let me know if the following resolves the problem for you? Also, please mark yourself as affected by [Bug #1811023 in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1811023) so this issue gets fixed.*

---

**Solution**

The following seems to have fixed the issue for me, and the GDM screen now appears without having to resort to the above "trick".

1. Edit the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`.

   ```
   sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules
   ```

   The original file looks like this:

   ```
   # disable Wayland on Hi1710 chipsets
   ATTR{vendor}=="0x19e5", ATTR{device}=="0x1711", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"
   # disable Wayland when using the proprietary nvidia driver
   DRIVER=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"
   ```

   Comment all of the lines as shown:

   ```
   # disable Wayland on Hi1710 chipsets
   # ATTR{vendor}=="0x19e5", ATTR{device}=="0x1711", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"
   # disable Wayland when using the proprietary nvidia driver
   # DRIVER=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-disable-wayland"
   ```

   Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.
2. Ensure that the Wayland is *not* disabled in GDM.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
   ```

   Comment the "WaylandEnable" line, if it is not already commented, as shown:

   ```
   # WaylandEnable=false
   ```

   Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. If you made changes, type <kbd>Y</kbd>, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.
3. Finally, reboot.

---

**Explanation**

The `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` file is supposed to prevent GDM from displaying the Wayland session option when the NVIDIA proprietary drivers are installed, since NVIDIA does not support Wayland.

However, in Ubuntu 20.04, there seems to be another redundant mechanism or rule that also prevents GDM from displaying the Wayland session option. I suspect this, because even after making the above change, the Wayland session option is still not displayed in GDM. (Setting `WaylandEnable=true` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` has no effect).

Therefore, I have a hunch that there are two conflicting rules, and disabling one of the rules (i.e. `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`) seems to remove the conflict.

Here is the `journalctl` boot log *before* making the above changes. You can see there is an error loading the "fb" module.

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (II) Loading sub module "fb"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (II) LoadModule: "fb"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]:         compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.0
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]:         ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: Xorg: ../../../../dix/privates.c:384: dixRegisterPrivateKey: Assertion `!global_keys[type].created' failed.
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (EE)
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[964]: (EE) Backtrace:
```

Here is the `journalctl` boot log *after* making the above changes. You can see the "fb" module loads successfully.

```
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]: (II) Loading sub module "fb"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]: (II) LoadModule: "fb"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]: (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]:         compiled for 1.20.9, module version = 1.0.0
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]:         ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1357]: (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
```

Comment: This is very interesting and beyond my pay grade, however I suffer from the same malady and found that editing the gdm rules as your have listed above fixes the problem for me.

Comment: @Charles Green, great! When you get a chance, please resister at launchpad and mark yourself as affected by this bug. If people don't report being impacted, it will never get fixed... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1811023

Comment: Alas, the behaviour has returned!

Comment: Looking journactl, I notice that the only error I see is `(EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied` -something has changed since Mar 1, as the fixes above did work for a while.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and `cat /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules`? (You can Edit your question and add the output there).

Comment: I wasn't the original question poster, but have the same issue.  I did do the wayland options.  Looking at xorg.0.log it appears that my graphics card driver is not being detected.  I have not yet had much time to examine this issue closely.

Comment: @Charles Green, Oh, I see. Your current issue is probably not this question. There are so many issues that go wrong with the Nvidia drivers, and the symptom is usually the same: black screen. Look for some other questions here on Askubuntu for your current problem. When you get your card to be recognized and install the driver correctly, this answer will (probably) fix the issue where your driver is correctly installed, but you get a black screen with a blinking cursor, and pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2 is the only way to get to GDM.

Comment: Even worse - I have purged the nvidia drivers from my system, and the error is coming form the integrated intel devices!

Comment: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321713/computer-does-not-complete-boot-cycle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321713/computer-does-not-complete-boot-cycle)

Comment: Relevant thread on the Nvidia forums: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-on-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-mobile-with-nvidia-driver-470/189029/5

Comment: This solved the issue for me

Comment: The fix from @Enterprise worked from me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have multiple monitors by any chance when you had this issue ? I have a similar issue ( *I have to `Ctrl-Alt-F2` then back to `Cltr-Alt-F1`* ) but I found a different answer / solution to the problem .. basically to do with what the "**Primary Display**" is.

If I have the **Primary Display** set to the external monitor ( connected via HDMI ), then I get the same issue. That is, I have to do the trick with `Ctrl-Alt-F2` then back to `Cltr-Alt-F1` to have the Gnome desktop login appear.

If I switch **Primary Display** to the laptop monitor, then I don't need to do the trick and the Gnome desktop login appears without issue :

[Multiple monitors : Black screen with blinking cursor and GNOME Desktop login only shows after switching console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389869/multiple-monitors-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-and-gnome-desktop-login-on)