# Nvidia drivers on ubuntu 20.04 isn't working!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a running ubuntu 20.04 system on my laptop with an intel i5 4200m processor and intel had graphics. So I switched my SSD on which the os was installed and installed it to my desktop pc which has a GT710 ( Nvidia ) graphics card on it. I also had a ubuntu 20.04 lts installed on it. For some personal reasons, I switched the hard drives. Everything was running okay but when I switched the Nvidia-460 driver from additional driver options on software & updates my display stopped working on next reboot. I tried with 450 too but it's not working. And the default open-source driver for the graphics card on ubuntu is not that eye-catching to me.

But I have ran the 450 driver on my previous ubuntu installation but on this it's not working. Is there any way to install the nvidia drivers on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS or any type of driver which is tested to run smoothly on Nvidia GT710 ?

Thanks is advance

Comment: Are you seeing a black screen with a blinking _ cursor?

Comment: Yes everytime when i switch to nvidia drivers.

Comment: I just posted this solution here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1310134/100356. Please let me know if it works for you by posting a comment on that answer.

Comment: @PJ OP does not yet have the comment everywhere privilege

Comment: Just leave a comment here then. (@Nmath, thaks for pointing that out).

Comment: @PJSingh thanks for the info but i am really tired of installing nvidia drivers, I have checked 450 460 and 38 something. Whenever I install them my screen goes black and I need to purge the drivers by removing the graphics card and by typing ctrl alt f2 on system boot up. it's just frustrating. 
i would use the open source one but it's very laggi and not that good.

Comment: on another thing i just upgraded my kernel now from 5.8 to 5.11 now my mouse is gone now. my cursor is looking like single dots now. any help on that?

Comment: What output do you get from $ sudo lshw -C display. If the driver is nouveau, you might need to change it to nvidia from Update Manager>>Additional drivers

Comment: No driver information only this. 
<br>
1description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:56 memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:ee000000-efffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
`

Comment: It sounds like you transplanted a hard drive from your laptop to your PC without reinstalling the OS.  No wonder you're having problems. Reinstall the OS on the new hardware.