# Black Screen after Booting - Ubuntu 20.04 - Dual Booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I had installed Ubuntu 20.04 with Dual Booting with Windows 10
It's installed in a Laptop with Nvidia 1660 TI
During the last month, when I try to boot into Ubuntu I only see a black screen, tried the nomodeset option [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it#:%7E:text=Black%2Fpurple%20screen%20after%20you,it%20to%20work%20with%20these.) in the GRUB menu but I till see everything black.

While booting with Recovery mode, I get the see the purple screen with the Recovery Menu for few seconds and then it turns black

Any Idea? should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia proprietary drivers installed in Ubuntu? If so, try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319463/100356.

Comment: To make the changes, try to login to Ubuntu "tty" (i.e. terminal only) using Ctrl+Alt+F2, otherwise you can ssh into your Ubuntu computer from another computer. Another option is to boot a Live USB, and chroot into your installed system (look for instructions here on AskUbuntu if you need to do that).