# Computer does not complete boot cycle

Tags: boot, 20.04, xorg, gdm

Version is `Linux dad 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've got a newer system76 which will complete grub and the initial boot menus, but which does not seem to start gdm3.  If I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, or log into the device after pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> I run can run `sudo systmctl restart gdm3` a normal display opens, and the device will run for days.  There is an Nvidia card in the system, however I do not currently have the drivers loaded.

This is consistent across reboots, and the problem has come and gone although I am unsure what updates are causing me issues.

It seems that Xorg is not detecting the integrated graphics device on the computer:  The first error in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` is

```
[     6.163] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:9bc4:1558:8520 rev 5, Mem @ 0xc3000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
```

And I get the errors described at https://wiki.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/#index8h2

My question is:  Should this be reported as a bug over at Launchpad somewhere?

Comment: Personally I'd suggest trying to the *development* release and seeing if it's a problem there (that's easier in my experience to get bugs noticed & fixed; *hirsute* is already partially frozen with the focus now on bug fixing..)  as I think there is more chance of getting fixes made if it's on say a LTS release (*focal*) and current *development* than say just *groovy* (which may also be impacted).

Comment: @guiverc Well, since all of the programs I depend on are running in *hirstute*, and I could setup a 20.04 vm for anything else...