# How to fix blank screen after boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it was working fine. But after installing some system updates, I am unable to access Ubuntu. I am on a dual boot system - Dell Inspiron 7560 with Nvidia Graphic Card. I have tried editing the Grub file by pressing the key e, and setting `nomodeset`. That didn't work. It either hangs at the blank screen with a pointer blinking or hangs up at Dell logo.

I tried using the Advanced Options and loaded onto the previous kernel installed. I was able to log into it after deleting my old configuration files. But in this mode, my external monitor is not being detected. I have tried to reinstall Nvidia Drivers and `lightdm` but to no luck.

Would greatly appreciate any help that I could have!

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04: Cursor blinking at boot after installing nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310134/ubuntu-20-04-cursor-blinking-at-boot-after-installing-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck. It still won’t work. After making the changes in the ‘gdm’ file, it still gets stuck on the same blinking cursor. 

M not sure why m able to log in if I use the previous version of the kernel though.

Comment: Ok. Hopefully someone else has a better suggestion for you.