# Display manager doesn't start with fresh 20.04.3 LTS install

Tags: system-installation, display, display-manager

I just installed 20.04.3 LTS as a dual-boot beside Windows 10, and the display manager isn't starting when I boot into Ubuntu. Any idea how to fix this?

Instead, I see a black screen with a tiny cursor underscore (`_`) blinking in the upper-left corner. If I view the logs by pressing `Alt-F7` all I see is a message about my boot partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p4: clean, 204105/1921360 files, 2608121/7680000 blocks`). I can login via a text prompt by pressing `Alt-F2`.

BTW, in the installation I selected the option to install additional / proprietary software.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the display manager `gdm3` was starting, and the blinking cursor was its output ([see this thread for reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310134/ubuntu-20-04-cursor-blinking-at-boot-after-installing-nvidia-drivers)).

I was able to fix things by manually installing nvidia drivers according to [these directions](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/) (see the command line section).

Comment: Next time make sure to select the option to allow installation of 3rd party drivers, codecs, firmware, etc. during Ubuntu installation. This way you don't have to install them *a posteriori* (and do it the hard way).

Comment: I did select that option. It appears it didn't fully work