# Black screen after installing Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, grub2, nvidia

There are many questions and answers covering this topic but all of them require to enter GRUB/recovery mode or to be able to get a CLI via pressing some key-combinations like e.g. `ctrl+alt+F1`, `ctrl+alt+F2`, `ctrl+alt+F6`, `ctrl+alt+F7`.

Non of that worked for me.

When trying to enter GRUB by pressing `shift` during boot, then the text "*GRUB loading*" was outputted on my screen followed by a black screen. I think, that already at this point my former Nvidia-driver-installation misbehaved and my PC entered GRUB but nothing was outputted to my display.

When I proceeded and Ubuntu was booted the system got stuck at a black screen with a blinking cursor. When I tried to type something in, there was no response from the system. The prompt just kept blinking.
When I have pressed `ctrl+alt+F1` followed by `ctrl+alt+F2`, I could swap between a totally black screen and a screen with the blinking cursor.
When I have pressed `ctrl+alt+F6`, then I was even able to type something in via my keyboard and I got a display response. Unfortunately, nothing has happened, when trying to type in any commands. It was also not the typical CLI Ubuntu prompt, rather just a simple blinking cursor and the text I have typed in. No *user-name:~$*-prompt.

Hence, I don't know what to do next. Are there any hints?

**What I have tried:**

1. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 desktop
2. After installation was ready I executed: `ubuntu-drivers devices`. Unfortunately, my needed driver version (Nvidia-driver 515) had the following warning: *"...package has invalid Support Pbheader, cannot determine support level..."*
3. After executing following commands, I could get rid of that warning:
   `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`
4. Then I have installed the recommended driver (Nvidia-driver 515) via `ubuntu-drivers devices`, `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515`.

**My system:**

1. Mainboard: Gigabyte Technology X58A-UD7
2. CPU: i7 920
3. GPU: GeForce GTX 970
4. HD: Samsung SSD

Comment: The answer of user "Enterprise" in the thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310134/ubuntu-20-04-cursor-blinking-at-boot-after-installing-nvidia-drivers has helped me to get a least a tty prompt where I can log in. Hence, I am able to switch from the black screen to tty.

Comment: You might try the Ubuntu 22.04 release, it had support for Wayland on Nvidia using the 515 driver, so less possibility of a mixup in the login Wayland support code.

Comment: @ubfan1. I think you are right. I tried it before my intent to install 20.04 but unfortunately I got problems with the installation-process of 22.04 from my usb life stick. But maybe I will try to fix these problems.