# Black Screen after boot with GeForce RTX 2080 Ti

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, nvidia

I have a desktop with GeForce RTX 2080 Ti.

After Ubuntu 20.04 Installation it loads straight onto a blank screen with a blinking cursor. I get a terminal on the system using <kbd>Ctrl + Alt  + F1</kbd>.

I first tried all the suggestions mentioned below

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1286728 - `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` followed by `sudo service gdm3 restart`
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1251028 - add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Tried rebooting and still got the same blank screen.

I read in some forums that the graphics card maybe the root cause of the issue. So I tried checking the compatible versions on NVidia's website as well as tried running `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E04sv000010DEsd000012AEbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti]
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I went with `nvidia-driver-460`. Tried rebooting after that and still booted up into the same blank screen. I tried running nvidia-smi and then something happened to the display. It showed multiple purple glitches across the screen and returned `No devices were found`

[image]

I tried purging and reinstalling the drivers as per this answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/1129890
The output for some of the commonly requested commands across the forum in similar scenarios have been highlighted

**lspci -vvv**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at a3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

**dmesg | grep NVRM**

```
[    2.758029] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.84  Wed May 26 20:14:59 UTC 2021
[    4.073016] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[    4.073070] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[    4.507083] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[    4.507166] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[    5.189855] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[    5.189875] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[    5.623500] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[    5.623520] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1165.397831] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1165.397902] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1165.830240] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1165.830257] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1179.773513] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1179.773531] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1180.202302] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1180.202325] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1416.634313] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1416.634352] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
[ 1417.063089] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: RmInitAdapter failed! (0x26:0xffff:1290)
[ 1417.063107] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: rm_init_adapter failed, device minor number 0
```

**dmesg | grep nvidia**

```
[    2.621823] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    2.758029] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.84  Wed May 26 20:14:59 UTC 2021
[    2.774304] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  460.84  Wed May 26 20:01:59 UTC 2021
```

Comment: Did you try `ubuntu-drivers install`? Try also classic `dpkg --configure -a; apt install -f`, check also logs with `journalctl -p err -k -b0 -xe`

Comment: Well if you can get a terminal up then someone in the community should be able to help. You can type `mokutil --sb-state` to confirm is fast boot is switched off (a common problem) and let us know. After a clean boot and then opening a terminal try `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` this works for me after ugrades but does not fix "human errors".

Comment: What CPU are you running, and what options do you have set on boot. Post the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`. If you have an AMD processor, then you may need `mem_encrypt=off` in your boot options.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `pcie_aspm=off` and `rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1` to kernel cmdline.

You could also try installing the latest drivers from the Nvidia website. I know this isn't ideal, but it might be an informative test:
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/

However, this looks like a hardware failure. Take a look at https://github.com/wilicc/gpu-burn and https://github.com/ComputationalRadiationPhysics/cuda_memtest to test your GPU memory.