# Ubuntu reboots but black screen

Tags: boot, command-line, screen

I wanted to only get the terminal of Ubuntu but got a black screen
The normal rebooting work but after that a black screen
Os: Lubuntu 20.04 a fork of ubuntu
The command: $ **sudo systemctl set-default multi-user"**
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you give us more information ? you mean you tried the command "sudo systemctl set-default multi-user" ? so you have access to a terminal

Comment: Lubuntu is a *flavor* of Ubuntu and not a fork.  It's built on the same Ubuntu infrastructure as Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core & more.. just using a different seed file (for 22.04 or *focal* it was https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/seeds/lubuntu.focal/desktop).  I'm not sure what you're actually asking for though; Ubuntu Desktop uses `gnome-terminal` ? is that what you want or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen with flashing cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251005/ubuntu-20-04-boots-to-black-screen-with-flashing-cursor)

Comment: @Saxtheowl thanks for your reply but i fixed my problem

Comment: Good work fixing your problem, but it would be great if you could still clarify the question to say more about what you did that caused the issue - that way your answer might be more useful to future readers - at the moment it is lacking context.

Answer (score 0):

I had edited some system files but found a fix

If you have root access to the terminal then run this command:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical
```

Or this one if you know your window manager:

```
sudo systemctl start "yourwmname"
```

And thanks to everyone who helped me.