# Installed nvidia drivers: black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, login-screen

I was running Wayland on 22.10 using nouveau on a GTX 550 Ti, and decided to install nvidia's 390 drivers using the Additional Drivers tool. The installation finished with asking me to reboot. After doing that I get to the Ubuntu splash screen, see some systemd output, and I'm then left with a black screen with a blinking cursor.

**Now what do I do?**

- I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1087050/428527) to allegedly force the login screen to use X, but that didn't make any difference.
- I tried doing a release upgrade, but I now have no network access. `nmcli c up` refuses to work with the message "No suitable device found for this connection [...]". I have no idea why; I used the connection to install the driver just before the reboot... Tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/1483416/36197) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632034/36197) to sort that out, to no avail.
- I tried adding `nomodeset` to grub [like so](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251028/428527). I don't see any improvement. Nor do I know what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a failed upgrade had installed a new kernel that all drivers must've been incompatible with, and it was apparently booting using that kernel.

Using the oldest installed kernel instead restored graphics and network access, at which point the upgrade could be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. It helped to uninstall nvidia drivers.

1. Boot in recovery mode
2. `apt-get prune nvida*`