# Install Ubuntu in dual boot with Windows7 (Boot in Bios Legacy / MBR)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my computer, currently there is Windows 7, and I would like to get to a dual boot situation with Ububtu.

I've read many post and articles, but I still have many doubts.

**My setup:**

I've got a computer with many Hard Disk:
One NTFS with Windows 7, three NTFS with normal data and one free SSD where I want to install Ubuntu.

Boot in Bios Legacy.

All hard disk are in MBR.

I've installed the Ubuntu ISO in my USB stick with "Ventoy".

**So, What can be a good procedure to follow?**

I have tried various ways, but nothing has worked. Now I stopped to avoid doing damages.

**I now describe the way I followed**

I've approximately followed [this](https://youtu.be/0pkwnRROncU?si=i_HDYE93FnsOEeGm) youtube video.

- In the BIOS I've disabled fast boot and secure boot mode.
- Lunched the instsallation from pen drive
- Choose "Something Else" option
  *Screenshot with "windows is not recognized (no detected operating systems)".*
  [image: windows is not recognized (no detected operating systems)]
- I've done this kind of partition table in my free disk
  [image]
- I've press "Install Now" and I've received this notice:
  "*No EFI System partition was found. This system  will likely not be able to boot successfully, and the installation process may fail.
  Please go back and add an EFI System Partition, or continue at your own risk.*"
- I continue the installation as the yt video tell me.
- Near the end of the installation I've got this error "*Executing 'grub-install /dev/sde1' failed. This is a fatal error.*" and the installation is stopped.
- I tried to correct this last error following [this](https://youtu.be/fleF4qDtwDE?si=OyR9oq-W82c5imnT) yt video, so,  repair with "Boot repair", I've got this message from "Boot repair": "*Legacy/Windows detected. The boot of your pc is in EFI mode. You may want to retry after changing it to BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode/. Are you sure you want to continue anyway?*" I've choose NO becaue I was not sure what I was really doing.
- Now I've also tried to add Ubuntu in the Bios Legacy boot loader with EasyBCD from windows (as the first [video](https://youtu.be/0pkwnRROncU?si=i_HDYE93FnsOEeGm) guide tell me), now I see the possibility to start ubuntu at computer startup, but it won't start, moreover with all these errors... (I cry).

I know that there are many informations about this on the web, but I still not have found a clean guide with my setup to follow (if you have, link to me please!).

many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing worked"? Why should Windows be recognized if it is on another storage device?

Comment: If system is that old to be BIOS/MBR, probably better to install a lighter weight flavor. Full Ubuntu is really more for newer UEFI based systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  You must use Something Else install option and choose drive & create / (root) partition. If using newer gpt, you need a 1MB unformatted bios_grub partition and must choose to install grub boot loader into that drive (not partition). Optional is separate /home or data partition(s). https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: @mikewhatever "nothing worked" in my procedure, now I've edited the post with the descriprion of all my wrong procedure. For the second question, surely you are right, I was thinking that it would be recognized even if it was in another storage, but I were in wrong.

Comment: @oldfred the requirements of my system seem to be fine, it's still a pretty powerful computer. Your procedure looks the same as the one I followed (I've just added it at my post!), but I had various errors and it didn't work

Comment: @karel  thanks! but I think no, there isn't the option "If your disk contains Windows installed in another storage".

Comment: Manual partitioning is basically equivalent to creating your own options assuming that the Ubuntu installer can detect all the existing partitions on the storage media.

Comment: How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it install. You show a bios_grub partition which is required for gpt partitioned drives in BIOS boot mode, so should just need to reinstall grub in BIOS mode. Boot your live installer in BIOS mode.Your UEFI boot menu should have two options to boot, one clearly UEFI as UEFI:xxxx and another xxxx where xxx is name or label of flash drive. Then add Boot-Repair and use advanced mode to reinstall grub to correct drive. Do not do autofix.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, after many attempts. I don't know if it is the best, but it worked.

Continuing from the steps described in my first post...

- I was not able to reinstall GRUB via "Boot repair", but it worked with "[super grub2 disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/)", so I put super grub2 disk in a USB pen drive, and I booted the system from it. So, I've choose this manual boot option show in the image below
  [image: super grub2 disk]
- I put these command (taken from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub#predefinito)):

  sudo grub-install /dev/sdX (in X the appropriate hard drive)

  sudo update-grub
- I restart the computer and I booted from the disk with Ubuntu, now i saw the operating systems menu for dual boot.
- while he was trying to boot ubuntu, it stopped with error "Failed to start casper-md5check"
  [image]
- I solved with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251028/1071111) guide
- Finaly my Ububtu was lunch correctly with the graphical interface.