# Ubuntu 22.04 boots to a black screen with a visible cursor

Tags: boot, 22.04

Similar to this issue [ubuntu-20-04-boots-to-black-screen-with-flashing-cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251005/ubuntu-20-04-boots-to-black-screen-with-flashing-cursor) Ubuntu 22.04 also boots to a black screen, however the linked solution doesn't appear to fix the issue for this version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If `WaylandEnable=false` is commented in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, uncomment `WaylandEnable=false` by removing the `#` character at the beginning of the line and rebooting.

At the black screen follow these steps:

1. Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> keyboard combination to show a virtual console.
2. Edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` with `sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
3. Uncomment out the line that contains `WaylandEnable=false` by removing the `#` character at the beginning of the line.
4. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano text editor which was launched by `sudoedit`.
5. Reboot with `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with the newest 22.04 update. What worked for me was `ctrl`+`alt`+`F1` to enter the `tty`, logging in and purging/updating the GPU drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I just started with a sudo reboot before any other thing. I got this.

Note: I also use grub to multiboot.

After a hard power off and power on everything works.

[image]